# Measure of $\{1,\frac12,\frac13,...\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Is the set $\{1,\frac12,\frac13,...\}$ of measure zero? Why?

Comment: What is your measure?

Comment: Measures are [countably subadditive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Measures_of_infinite_unions_of_measurable_sets), so whenever all singletons have measure zero, all countable subsets have measure zero.

Comment: What's the definition of the measure of a sequence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R$, any countable set is of measure zero.

Answer (score 3):

Take any $\,\epsilon>0\,$ and take the open intervals

$$I_n:=\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}\,,\,\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}\right)\Longrightarrow \left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}I_n\,\,,\,\;\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty|I_n|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n-1}}<\epsilon$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is a reason that wouldn't work for an arbitrary countable set, but works in this case (or for other sets of terms of a convergent sequence).

For all $\varepsilon>0$,

$$\left\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\ldots\right\}\subset(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\cup\text{(a finite set)},$$ which implies that the measure is at most

$$2\varepsilon+\text{(the measure of a finite set)}.$$

If you can show that the measure of an arbitrary finite set is $0$ (perhaps a good warmup for the countable case), then you can conclude that the measure must be $0$, because it is smaller than each positive number.